# Copying cells from one sheet to another with Google Apps Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy specific cells from one sheet to another using a button as a trigger. The same script should also send an email notification to notify someone that the document has been updated.

This is the code I am using but it does not work and it seems incomplete:

```
function myFunction() { MailApp.sendEmail({ to: "xx@xx.com.au", subject: "xx", htmlBody: " xxx", }

function Copy() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('xxx'); 
var range = ss.getRange('xx'); 
var data = range.getValues(); 
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxx'); //replace with destination ID 
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('xxx'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
}
```

I need the script to copy the cells and add them to an existing sheet and not overwrite any rows too.

Comment: Can you please format your code using new lines and edit your post? Any way where are you trying to copy in the code. You have only tried to open two files

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work and it seems incomplete"? Are you getting an error? What is missing on your script?